# Reading array from threads, c, cygwin

Tags: arrays, multithreading, semaphore, progress, percentage

I'm pretty new to threads and would like some insight. I'm trying to get the percentage each thread has completed for its calculation. Each thread will report its percentage to a different element of the same array. I have this working with `pthread_join` immediately after `pthread_create` and a separate thread for reading all the values of the array and printing the percentage but when I have all threads running after each other without waiting for the previous one to finish I get some weird behavior. This is how I'm accessing the shared (global) array.

```
//global
int *currentProgress;
//main
    currentProgress = malloc(sizeof(int)*threads);
    for(i=0; i<threads; i++)
        currentProgress[i] = 0;
//child threads
currentProgress[myId] = (int)percent; //myId is unique

//progress thread
for(i=0; i<threads; i++)
    progressTotal += currentProgress[i];
progressTotal /= threads;
printf("Percent: %d", progressTotal);
```

This is essentially the code I think is not being used correctly for multi-threads. When I print out the state of the shared array, I notice that as soon as another thread starts accessing the array (different element though), the previous element immediately goes to some random number... `-2147483648` and when the latter element finishes the prior element continues like normal. Should I be using semaphores for this? I thought I could access different elements of an array at the same time and I thought reading them wasn't an issue.

This is the entire code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STDIN 0


int counter = 0;
uint64_t *factors;
void *getFactors(void *arg);
void *deleteThreads(void *arg);
void *displayProgressThread(void *arg);
int *currentProgress;

struct data
{
    uint64_t num;
    uint64_t incrS;
    uint64_t incrF;
    int threads;
    int member;
} *args;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc < 3) {printf("not enough arguments"); exit(1);}

    int i;
    int threads = atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t thread_id[threads];
    pthread_t dThread;

    currentProgress = malloc(sizeof(int)*threads);
    for(i=0; i<threads; i++)
        currentProgress[i] = 0;

    args = (struct data*)malloc(sizeof(struct data));
    args->num = atoll(argv[1]);
    args->threads = threads;

    uint64_t increment = (uint64_t)sqrt((uint64_t)args->num)/threads;
    factors = (uint64_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint64_t)*increment*threads);

    pthread_create(&dThread, NULL, displayProgressThread, (void*)args);

    //for the id of each thread
    args->member = 0;
    for(i=0; i<threads; i++)
    {
            args->incrS = (i)*increment +1;
            args->incrF = (i+1)*increment +1;
            pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, getFactors, (void*)args);
            usleep(5);
    }

    for(i=0; i<threads; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("done\n");
    for (i=0; i<counter; i++)
        printf("\n%llu : %llu", factors[++i], factors[i]);
    return 0;
}

void *getFactors(void *arg)
{
    uint64_t  count;
    int myId;
    int tempCounter = 0, i;
    struct data *temp = (struct data *) arg;
    uint64_t number = temp->num;
    float total = temp->incrF - temp->incrS, percent;

    myId = temp->member++;

    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

    for(count=temp->incrS; count<=temp->incrF; count++)
    {

        percent = (float)(count-temp->incrS)/total*100;
        currentProgress[myId] = (int)percent;

        if (number%count == 0)
         {
                factors[counter++] = count;
                factors[counter++] = number/count;
         }   
        usleep(1);
    }
    usleep(1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *displayProgressThread(void *arg)
{
    struct data *temp = (struct data *) arg;
    int toDelete = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        int i;
        int progressTotal = 0;
        char *percent = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
        for(i=0; i<toDelete; i++)
            printf("\b \b");

        for(i=0; i<temp->threads; i++){
            progressTotal += currentProgress[i];
        }

        progressTotal /= temp->threads;
        printf("|");
        for(i=0; i<50; i++)
            if(i<progressTotal/2)
                printf("#");
            else
                printf("_");
        printf("| ");
        sprintf(percent, "Percent: %d", progressTotal);
        printf("%s", percent);
        toDelete = 53 + strlen(percent);


usleep(1000);
    fflush(stdout);
    if(progressTotal >= 100)
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

}

Comment: I guess you have to put the complete code here as the order of doing things is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some non synchronized pieces of code that are accessed by the threads which cause this problem.

One first place to be synchronized is:

```
   myId = temp->member++;
```

But more importantly is that, the main thread is doing:

```
   args->incrS = (i)*increment +1;
   args->incrF = (i+1)*increment +1;
```

while at the same time in the threads:

```
   for(count=temp->incrS; count<= temp->incrF; count++)
    {

        percent = (float)(count-temp->incrS)/total*100;
        currentProgress[myId] = (int)percent;

        if (number%count == 0)
         {
                factors[counter++] = count;
                factors[counter++] = number/count;
         }   
        usleep(1);
    }
```

The unsynchronized accesses mentioned above affect the calculation of `percent` value which results in such abnormal happenings. You have to do synchronization in all these places in order to get the kind of behavior you would expect.

Comment: Thank you. I saw the Id part of the problem but completely over looked the increments. I'm working on writing a sem class using mutexs and conditional variables but until then I'll just assign these to new data and put the main thread to sleep for a bit while that happens.

Comment: I would suggest moving all the concurrent `read/write` operations to some properly synchronized methods. In the meantime, fetching `temp->incrS` and `temp->incrF` into some local variables **before** the `for` loop and using those variables inside the loop **might** also help.